# Using forms timer with changing interval

Tags: c#, winforms

### Traffic Light simulation in WindowsForm C#

My question is how to set timer 30s for red and green light and 5s for yellow light?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            redLight.Visible = true;
            yellowLight.Visible = false;
            greenLight.Visible = false;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void greenLight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (redLight.Visible == true)
            {
                redLight.Visible = false;
                yellowLight.Visible = true;
                greenLight.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (yellowLight.Visible == true)
            {
                redLight.Visible = false;
                yellowLight.Visible = false;
                greenLight.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(greenLight.Visible == true)
            {
                redLight.Visible = true;
                yellowLight.Visible = false;
                greenLight.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timer class like in the code below. There is no logic for yellow as I didn't know how much time between yellow and red you need and it would be a nice example for you to solve.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            redLight.Visible = true;
            yellowLight.Visible = false;
            greenLight.Visible = false;
            myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            myTimer.Interval = 30000;
            myTimer.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (redLight.Visible == true)
            {
                myTimer.Interval = 5000;
                redLight.Visible = false;
                yellowLight.Visible = true;
                greenLight.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (yellowLight.Visible == true)
            {
                redLight.Visible = false;
                yellowLight.Visible = false;
                greenLight.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(greenLight.Visible == true)
            {
                myTimer.Interval = 30000;
                redLight.Visible = true;
                yellowLight.Visible = false;
                greenLight.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```